# I am unable to execute netcat command within docker bash terminal?

Tags: bash, docker, ubuntu, netcat

I am a beginner in docker . 
I have installed docker-ce in my ubuntu 18.04 machine using command
`sudo apt install docker-ce`

As part of a tutorial , I am trying to establish connection between containers by executing series of below commands.

> Below command will turn on ports 1234/4321 to listen to traffic inside/outside of containers i'm going to use.

```
root@ghost-SVE9999CNS:/home/ghost# docker run --rm -ti -p 1234:1234 -p 4321:4321 --name echo-server ubuntu:18.04 bash
```

> Now, I wanted to run netcat commands within docker bash terminal.

```
root@xxxyyyyzzzz12:/# nc -lp 1234 | nc -lp 4321
```

Once i inovke above command from my terminal.. Its giving errors "nc: command not found"

```
bash: nc: command not found
bash: nc: command not found
```

Later, I have done enough research and i never found any official docker solution for this problem.

Please could anyone help me out installing netcat within docker-ce.
I've tried commands like below.

```
apt-get install netstat
apt-get install nc
```

But, no luck.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

`nc` is not installed by default on `ubuntu:18.04` image, so you have to install it :

```
apt-get update && apt-get install -y netcat
```

`apt-get update` is necessary to first update list of packages (when the container is started, this list is empty). Once done, you can run `nc -lp 1234` from the container.

To test all works as you expected, you can then :

- run from a shell (on your host) something like `telnet container_ip 1234` or `telnet localhost 1234` (since ports have been forwarded)
- type something
- look at the container output to see what you typed in your host shell

Answer (score 1):

It is not necessary to use `ubuntu:18.04` to follow the tutorial, you can use `ubuntu:14.04` for example, in which `nc` installed by default.

`docker run --rm -ti -p 1234:1234 -p 4321:4321 --name echo-server ubuntu:14.04 bash`